# how to alter drupal comment $submitted variable?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

now,i want to the comment display as this style: my drupal version is drupal 6.20

```
    comment  author

        comment content

     the created date of the comment
```

how to get that effect. thank you, i know the date and comment author are default output by the $submit variable. so i can't separate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no $submit variable :) And the saved information has nothing to do with they way that information is presented.

I think what you want is to adjust the [comment.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes--garland--comment.tpl.php/6/source) template and/or extend [template_preprocess_comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/6). Copy the template into your theme directory and start adjusting it. See http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [devel_themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module, click on that element, the module will suggest for the preprocess function.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out [here](http://drupal.org/node/999912) also

Go to `/admin/content/node-type/blog` (assuming that's the node-type you're using) and you should see a heading for `Comment Settings`.Change them accordingly.

But this only for when you are on the specific story page. To make the comments display from the main page where all the front-paged stories are herded then Views module is what you need - it'll let you create a page which has certain stories plus their comments; you can then allocate that as the front page.

Comment: thanks for you reply. change those settings can't get what i want. the thing i want that is do some changes to the comment $submit variable